# SSH key exchange is not working

Tags: ssh

Is there any way to verify why SSH key exchange between 2 servers is not working?

In Server A:
I did the following steps:

```
ssh-keygen –t rsa
cd /.ssh
cp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys
```

Then in Server B:
I created the `.ssh` directory and uploaded the `authorized_keys` from Server A

I tried logging in from Server A to Server B but the system is still prompting me to enter password.

I tried using this: On server(A) you connect via ssh user1@host? You might try ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey user1@host but it show permission denied Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).

Any advise on how to check what is wrong? Just additional info in Server A i am not using the root account.

Comment: I tried using this: On server(A) you connect via ssh user1@host? You might try ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey user1@host but it show permission denied Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).

Answer (score 3):

Try `ssh -v` this should provide additional information about the authentication process.

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive,hostbased
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/nce/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
```

Just to confirm your steps:
You created a keypair via ssh-keygen
Then you uploaded the key at `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the server(B) and appended it to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` for the user1.

On server(A) you connect via `ssh user1@host`?  You might try `ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey user1@host`

And you could provide a special/different identityfile by `ssh -i ~/.ssh/serverB/id_rsa user1@host`

Comment: I tried using this: On server(A) you connect via ssh user1@host? You might try ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey user1@host but it show permission denied Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).

Answer (score 2):

Check the permissions of the serverb authorized_keys file. If it has write permission for group/other then login using public keys will fail and fall back to password if it's available. If required change the permissions on the authorized_keys file to 644.

Possible but less likely is that you have public key authentication disables in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. Check that the config file does not contain a line

```
PubkeyAuthentication no
```

IF it does just comment it out (the default is yes) and restart the sshd service.

Comment: And the permissions on serverB:~/.ssh should be 700.

Comment: +1 also check the file owner, it has to be the user who is logging in.

Comment: Permissions on authorized_keys should be 600, not 644.

Comment: @slillibri With perms at 644 you can still log in so sshd disagrees with you.

Answer (score 1):

A tip for you: take a look at serverB's sshd log (`/var/log/secure` on Red Hat based)

http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#3.14

And for the future, you should use `ssh-copy-id` instead of manual copy.

Comment: checking var/log/secure saved my days else it would have ruined my day. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Check to see whether sshd on B is configured to accept key-based authentication. On RedHat based systems the config file is /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Answer (score 0):

This command should not work:

```
cd /.ssh
```

Is that a typo or were you in the wrong place when you copied the id_rsa.pub file to authorized_keys?

Log into server B and `cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to see if it contains what is in the same file on server A.

Note, it is not important that you keep the authorized_keys file on server A as it is not used in the authentication transaction from server A to server B. You just need the id_rsa file in ~.ssh/ on server A.