# SSH public key authentication issue

Tags: ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSH key exchange is not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/319010/ssh-key-exchange-is-not-working)

In Server A: I did the following steps:

```
ssh-keygen –t rsa
cd /.ssh
cp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys
```

Then in Server B: I created the .ssh directory and uploaded the authorized_keys from Server A

I tried logging in from Server A to Server B but the system is still prompting me to enter password.

Can anyone advise? Below is the ouput i got when using the following command:

```
ssh -v -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey user@host

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /export/home/user/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying public key: /export/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publicke
y,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /export/home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/319010/ssh-key-exchange-is-not-working???

Answer (score 1):

try command

```
ssh-copy-id user@machine
```

it should copy your key automatically.

Comment: i tried running this command and it says file not found

Comment: it means that your pub key not in .ssh/ folder

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of the authorized_keys file on server B. It should be at most 644. Check the permissions on the .ssh directory they should be 700. Check the authorized_keys file is owned by the account tying to log in.

Comment: i check the permission is correct