# permission denied using a public key with Copssh on a windows 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssh, permissions, sftp

I've a Windows 2003 SP2 server with CopSSH version 1.1.0.1 installed.
I've a user set up for SFTP who is able to transfer files from two servers.
I am trying to add the public keys he provided me so that he can transfer files from three additional servers.
I've added the keys by opening a BASH shell and using the command line to navigate to that users home directory and then doing this command
cat your public key >> authorized_keys

Opening the authorized_keys file in a text editor, I see that the new keys were added.

After adding the new keys, I stopped and then restarted the opensshserver.

When the user tries a test from one of the new servers, he is getting a error
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
lost connection

Following the recommendations of an answer to a similar question on stackoverflow (

chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

The user is still getting the Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSH key exchange is not working](http://serverfault.com/questions/319010/ssh-key-exchange-is-not-working)